# Trying to POST json data from Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, json

I have modified http://fivefilters.org/term-extraction/ this project so that:

Given input (https://gist.github.com/4426264) of text the python script term-extraction.py outputs keywords in json format and sends via POST the json to a php file
term-extraction.py -> echo.php

link to term-extraction.py https://gist.github.com/4426181
link to echo.php https://gist.github.com/4426193

here is the json output given by the php script: https://gist.github.com/4426197
here is the output of term-extraction.py : http://jsfiddle.net/Bw7UX/

here is the desired array output that I would like to be passed into php: https://gist.github.com/4426208

So, my problem essentially is that:

```
Array
(
    [json] => None
)
```

I would like the php array to have the value of all the keywords from the python script, like this link: https://gist.github.com/4426208

```
array(42) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "rajaratnam"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "court"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "district court"
...
[41]=>
string(6) "appeal"
}
```

I think my problem may be with line 69 thru 78 of term-extraction.py and specifically this line:

```
mydata=[('json',  self.response.out.write(json.dumps(list, indent=0)))] #trying to create an
```

Thanks in advance for your replies, I am very new to python so I appreciate the patience.

edit: This is the output when the script is run. I do not get why the json is being output from they python script but it is not in the PHP array properly. 
`
START echo.php

NULL

echoing post json: 
POST ITEMS:
NO POST ITEMS 
Array
(
)
END echo.php

Status: 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/plain Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 533 { "json": [ "rajaratnam", "court", "district court", "sec", "court papers", "securities fraud", "court records", "galleon group", "exchange commission", "sakthi prasad", "u.s", "case", "judgment", "group", "securities", "gupta", "district", "sakthi", "right", "co", "founder", "penalties", "raj", "consulting", "days", "manager", "conspiracy", "year", "years", "prasad", "inc", "network", "lawsuit", "editing", "vs", "sachs", "galleon", "commission", "reuters", "papers", "tips", "appeal" ] }
`

Comment: Please do not use gists to show example code and input. Put *all* examples in your post. Nothing guarantees that GitHub will have the same lifespan as SO.

Comment: @Martijn My apologies. Point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that self.response.out.write function returns None. I think on line 69 you should have:

```
mydata = json.dumps({'json': list}, indent=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I get this error when I try your code: https://gist.github.com/4429449

Comment: urlencode uses a dict as argument. Try: `mydata={'json': json.dumps(list, indent=0)}`

Comment: I appreciate the continued help! @sneawo
Unfortunately I get a similar error: 
https://gist.github.com/4431297

Comment: Do you think it might be a good idea to output `list ` as a string? and then post the string? 
It seems that both errors had one common thing, they were getting hung up at:
`mydata=urllib.urlencode(mydata)`

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to python. I tried to print out mydata with a for loop but it isn't working. Could you help me print it out? I apologize for my novice.

Comment: thanks so much for the continued help @sneawo!
here is the output of `print mydata` is when i use  `mydata={'json': json.dumps(list, indent=0)}` as you suggested in your second reply.
https://gist.github.com/4441888
(please forgive me for using a gist again.. `mydata` was too long for the reply)
NOTE: here is the entire output of the script: 
https://gist.github.com/4441899

Comment: sorry, i tried urlencode your mydata and it works for me. also it's strange that the value in mydata has list type, should be string `{'json': '["rajaratnam", "court",...]'}`

Comment: Is there any alternative to URL encode? I guess it doesn't make much sense to me that I have to URL encode POST data

Answer (score 0):

Am not familiar with python, but trying to help.

Are you sure that you have converted the 'json data' as a 'string' before sending it to php?
Try to pass hard-coded strings ({'name':'Alex'}) and see whats happening on php end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I do:
    mydata=[('json',  'test')]
json has the value of 'test'
So it works with a hard coded string.